# How to create scroll view for textinput when we click scroll it can drag

Tags: react-native

I want to create a scroll view that can be **clickable** and I can scroll by *clicking* to scrollbar for `<textinput>`. Tried `scrollview` of react but it does not work it only shows scroll but it's not clickable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for scrolling drop-down.
Please check these npm packages.

1. react-native-searchable-dropdown
2. react-native-picker-select

Please try links in the comment.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-dropdown
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker